# Java Swing JSlider addChangeListener error

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, runtime-error

I am using Swing to make a simple GUI but when I add a change listener to a JSlider, I get the following runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at XMovePanel.<init>(XMovePanel.java:15)
```

My code is the following:

```
public class XMovePanel extends JPanel
{
    JSlider xCoord;
    private GUIApp d;
    private XMoveListener xmove;

    public XMovePanel(GUIApp d)
    {
    this.d = d;
    xmove = new XMoveListener();

    // Error occurs here:
    xCoord.addChangeListener(xmove);

        // Settings for the slider
  private class XMoveListener implements ChangeListener{
@Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event){

        // Change listener does stuff on action here
```

But I don't know why I would get an error when I add the change listener. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `xCoord` is null; try this instead:

```
JSlider xCoord = new JSlider();
```

Addendum: Because `xCoord` is an instance variable and it is meant to reference a `JSlider`, [*JLS 4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.5) specifies that "the default value is `null`." Trying to invoke a method on a null reference throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks, silly me, I saw I tried to add the listener *before* I made the JSlider

Comment: I've done the same thing. At least Java throws an exception, rather than silently dereferencing memory address zero!